# multiple conditional PercentRank statement in excel

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, percentile

I'm trying to calculate PercentRank within different groups such that an elements with Blank label are ranked against all elements in the population while others with common labels are ranked against all elements sharing that particular same label.

```
 ID element value   expected outcome
 1. Blank   20         0.333
 2. Yellow  5          0
 3. Yellow  24         1
 4. Blue    33         1
 5. Blank   34         1
 6. Blue    27         0
```

element 1 and 5 will be ranked against element 1 to 6 while elements 2 and 4 will only be ranked against elements 3 and 6 respectively.

Comment: What is your expected output from the above?

Comment: @WeirdsourcerBayo how can do you come up with those calculated ranks? There are, for instance, only 2 *yellow* elements, so their ranks have to be 0% and 100% - same for *blue*

Comment: @UlliSchmid that's true, mistake form my side

Comment: @WeirdsourcerBayo I guess then we only differ on one value - how is the 0.333 for "Blank" (value 20) calculated? If you rank it *"against all elements in the population"*, you get 20% don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming

- column A holds your classes ("Blank", "Yellow", "Blue")
- column B holds your values (20,5,24,..)

enter this into C1:

```
=IF(A1="Blank",PERCENTRANK(B$1:B$6,B1),PERCENTRANK(IF(A$1:A$6=A1,B$1:B$6,""),B1))
```

and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter it as an array formula. Then copy cell C1 to C2:C6.

result:

[image]